# xfs_repair is stuck - safe to kill it?

Tags: linux, mount, repair, xfs

Centos 6.9

So, I had two 40TB volumes fail, at least nominally, after reconfiguring the raid they're a part of. The raid volumes are ok, but when mounting them, one reported "can't read superblock", the other "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock".

I then made the mistake of running xfs_repair on both at the same time (they're on the same file server), which I now understand was asking for memory problems. The file server has 64GB ram with half as much swap. So the server ran out of memory and one of the xfs_repair processes was killed. Now the second one is still running, but it's stuck for a long time now with no progress and 0% cpu usage.

I figure I have to kill the stuck xfs_repair process, but that makes me nervous. Is there something else I might try?

As for the other volume that was being repaired and whose process was killed, I tried mounting it and it's mounting properly now.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it is not safe to kill a process doing low level manipulation. In your case though, you have a safety net since the other drive is working.

Assuming these are two volumes setup as RAID 1, you can now unmount the one that works (just for extra safety), kill the xfs_repair process and assess the state of the one that was interrupted, then just restore the good one (unmounted earlier) into it if it is not working.

Given that the process is at 0% usage, it is probably deadlocked which means it *must* be killed and that would be the case even if it was safe or not. A shutdown or reboot would implicitly kill it anyway, so I suggest you go ahead and do it yourself, so have more control over what is happening. If some thing bad happens, it probably happened already or was unavoidable.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation of my thoughts. I've killed the process and the volume mounts cleanly now. However xfs_check sees some errors so I'll run xfs_repair again, one volume at a time, and limit its memory usage.